# tflite With Dynamic Size Input Shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am converting the .pb model in to tflite. I am using image pyramid with fully convolutional network at inference time. But it is showing this error (without using resize_tensor_input)

```
ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Dimension mismatch. Got 150 but expected 300 for dimension 1 of input 35.
```

After using resize_tensor_input before allocate_tensors() again it throwing error.

```
RuntimeError: tensorflow/lite/kernels/reshape.cc:66 num_input_elements != num_output_elements (13300 != 56550)Node number 26 (RESHAPE) failed to prepare.
```

My tensorflow version is 1.15.2
How can we set the tflite input tensor with dynamic size?

Answer (score 0):

TFLite has lots of improvement with 2.x release with better converter and op supports. You might want to try it with TF 2.X releases.

To migration TF1 to TF2,
Please check https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate